# Cost of calling Copy constructor and Normal Constructor

Tags: c++, design-patterns

In prototype design pattern,the clone method of abstract base class is implemented as below

```
/* From Wikipedia */
class Prototype
{
public:
    virtual ~Prototype() { }

    virtual Prototype* clone() const = 0;
};

class ConcretePrototype : public Prototype
{
  ...
  virtual ConcretePrototype* clone() const 
  { 
      return new ConcretePrototype(*this); 
  } 
};
```

The client creates an object and then calls clone() method to create a copy of the object

Is new ConcretePrototype(*this) cheaper than new ConcretePrototype( ) ?

Comment: Whether it is cheaper is irrelevant here. You need a copy.

Comment: I am not sure it is irrelevant. The answer is "no" but that doesn't make it a bad question.

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe no. It depends entirely on what the two constructors do.

Comment: I would say that if the writer of the class makes an accessible copy constructor it should be at least as efficient as creating a copy via a default constructor followed by an assign or whatever. So the answer is "no" but they might on occasion be equal.

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand the purpose of `clone()`.

It is a "virtual copy constructor".

Constructors cannot actually be virtual (not even copy constructors). Therefore, the solution is to have a method you can call on the object you already have to make an exact copy.

A cloned copy has its own lifetime so it is safe to destroy the original.

Normally you would expect the implementation class to have a private or protected copy constructor so you cannot call it directly.

You don't even have to know the type of the object you are cloning. And note the "co-variant" return type.

I don't know what you mean exactly by "cheaper". If you implement a copy-constructor for your class it should normally be at least as efficient, and commonly more efficient than creating an empty instance of your class then copying into it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `copy c-tor` in this pattern, since it's sense of the pattern.
But in other cases - all depends on actions in `default` constructor and in `copy-constructor`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question is, given the code:

```
ConcretePrototype original;
{some code}
ConcretePrototype copy1;
copy1 = *orignal.clone();
ConcretePrototype copy2(original);
```

Is creation of `copy1` more costly than `copy2`. It the only way I can see you can compare `default c-tor` with `copy c-tor` and use clone in one code example.

Most probably yes. How much? Hard to say.
Default constuctor might be implemented in a way it creates a shallow copy, so there would be little overhead.